# Python Pandas add column to multi-index GroupBy DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to add a column to a Pandas GroupBy DataFrame with a multi-index. The column is the difference between the max and mean value of a common key after grouping.

Here is the input DataFrame:

```
   Main  Reads  Test  Subgroup
0     1      5    54         1
1     2      2    55         1
2     1     10    56         2
3     2     20    57         3
4     1      7    58         3
```

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Main': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1], 'Reads': [5, 2, 10, 20, 7],\
                   'Test':range(54,59), 'Subgroup':[1,1,2,3,3]})

result = df.groupby(['Main','Subgroup']).agg({'Reads':[np.max,np.mean]})
```

Here is the variable `result` before perform the calculation of `diff`:

```
              Reads     
               amax mean
Main Subgroup           
1    1            5    5
     2           10   10
     3            7    7
2    1            2    2
     3           20   20
```

Next, I calculate the `diff` column with:

```
result['Reads']['diff'] = result['Reads']['amax'] - result['Reads']['mean']
```

but here is the output:

```
/home/userd/test.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/
...stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
...result['Reads']['diff'] = result['Reads']['amax'] - result['Reads']['mean']
```

I would like the `diff` column to be at the same level a `amax` and `mean`.

Is there a way to add a column to the innermost (bottom) column index of a multi-index `GroupBy()` object in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#you can you lambda to build diff directly.
df.groupby(['Main','Subgroup']).agg({'Reads':[np.max,np.mean,lambda x: np.max(x)-np.mean(x)]}).rename(columns={'<lambda>':'diff'})
Out[2360]: 
              Reads          
               amax mean diff
Main Subgroup                
1    1            5    5    0
     2           10   10    0
     3            7    7    0
2    1            2    2    0
     3           20   20    0
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful.

Comment: Could you explain the `lambda` inside the embedded `list`? I am not sure I understand why it needs to be there.

Comment: The lambda is just another function you apply to 'Reads', just like the np.max and np.mean functions you have put there. What this means is all the functions in the dict will be applied to 'Reads', thus creating 3 separate columns.

Comment: Nice solution, quite straight-forward!

Comment: Thanks you. This will be most useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the multi-index using a tuple

```
result[('Reads','diff')] = result[('Reads','amax')] - result[('Reads','mean')]
```

You get

```
                    Reads
                    amax    mean    diff
Main    Subgroup            
1       1           5       5       0
        2          10      10       0
        3           7       7       0
2       1           2       2       0
        3          20      20       0
```

Comment: Just brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [8]: result = df.groupby(['Main','Subgroup']).agg({'Reads':[np.max,np.mean, lambda x: x.max()-x.mean()]})

In [9]: result
Out[9]:
              Reads
               amax mean <lambda>
Main Subgroup
1    1            5    5        0
     2           10   10        0
     3            7    7        0
2    1            2    2        0
     3           20   20        0

In [10]: result = result.rename(columns={'<lambda>':'diff'})

In [11]: result
Out[11]:
              Reads
               amax mean diff
Main Subgroup
1    1            5    5    0
     2           10   10    0
     3            7    7    0
2    1            2    2    0
     3           20   20    0
```

Comment: Plus one as usual :)